# Angular 8 Reset Select option inside ngFor

Tags: angular, angular8

Below is the code which is creating Select controls.

```
 <select class="form-control" #tempSelect (change)="priorityChangedChk($event,wt)" style="width:160px">
          <option value="0">Select a Priority</option>
          <option *ngFor="let wto of wtpFrmDB; let j=index" [ngValue]="wto">
            {{j + 1}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

This is how Selects are created

[image]

Now if I make a selection in one of the select I perform a validation and if that validation fails, I simply need to RESET ONLY THE CURRENT SELECT i.e. I need to set this to again "Select a Priority".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the select control in the method:

```
<select class="form-control" #tempSelect (change)="priorityChangedChk(tempSelect, $event,wt)" style="width:160px">
          <option value="0">Select a Priority</option>
          <option *ngFor="let wto of wtpFrmDB; let j=index" [ngValue]="wto">
            {{j + 1}}
          </option>
</select>
```

And reset the value:

```
priorityChangedChk(c, e, wt) {
  // Your logic
  if (true) {
    c.value = "0";
  }
}
```

How to disable?

```
c.disabled = true;
```

How to get value?

```
c.value
```

Remember `c` is your native element. You can apply whatever available in JS to manipulate the control.

Comment: This seems to be classic example of using template variable. Can i also enable and disable the select ?

Comment: @Rishabh Do you mean to disable the select completely if validation fails?

Comment: yes exactly and also how to collect this changed value ?

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I was creating the template variable but was not able to make it's use somehow.

Comment: So I believe template variable is the only way we can handle individual controls which gets created in a loop. Is it ?

Comment: @Rishabh you can also use Reactive Forms.

Answer (score 0):

Bind select with [(ngModel)]="selectedValue"

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" #tempSelect (change)="priorityChangedChk($event,wt)" style="width:160px">
          <option value="0">Select a Priority</option>
          <option *ngFor="let wto of wtpFrmDB; let j=index" [ngValue]="wto">
            {{j + 1}}
          </option>
        </select>
```

when validation fails  set

```
this.selectedValue = 0
```

hope this will work

Comment: doing this makes the effect on all the selects which gets created. So this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's code I use. it may or may not help because i'm not using form-control:

```
    <select id="componentSelect"
        (change)="addNewComponent($event.target.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let option of options">{{option}}</option>
    </select>
```

typescript:

```
addNewComponent(name: string) {
  //do something
  changeSelectedOption('componentSelect', 'Select a Priority');
}
```

javascript:

```
function changeSelectedOption(id, value) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if (e)
    e.value = value;
}
```